# WordPress and automated MySQL backups to a different host

Tags: database, mysql, backup

I'm having the following setup. A development computer in my local network and a production server with a real internet domain. Developing the PHP/CSS files on my dev computer for my theme is handled with `git`, I can easily deploy them to the production system. Up until now everything works fine.

But on my dev system I also want to always have a reasonably new database dump from my real system. Now, the quick and dirty way would be do simply write a cronjob to do a `mysqldump` on the production server and a `mysql < dumpfile` on the dev computer. But since Wordpress holds the hostnames in it's database, this would lead to a non-working dev system, because all links would be wrong.

I know of https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress, but the steps there require a lot of manual hick-hack (editing config files, etc.), so this is not good to be used for automation. Well, doing a lot `chmod` and `sed` and `mv` and so on could also be automated, but this feels rather "hacky".

What would be a correct, clean way of handling such automated DB backups without breaking things?

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugins such as BackupBuddy, but I prefer to script this and use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/), which reads wp-config.php and means you don't have to worry about mysql credentials.

wp-cli allows you to:

- export the db: `wp db export <filename>`
- import the db: `wp db import <filename>`
- safe search and replace (including serialised data): `wp search-replace <search-string> <replace-string>`

So, I have a script that

- executes `wp export` on a remote server via ssh
- copies the sql export file via scp to my local machine
- executes `wp import` locally
- executes `wp search-replace`

You could then add it to cron, but I prefer to run it manually - takes less than a minute to sync db from production to my local environment.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I need to read about and test a bit with `wp-cli` first if it really meets my needs, before I accept, but I'm confident. :)